# Delay automatic url redirect with jquery?

Tags: jquery, url, redirect, delay

I need a transition page that will display for 2 seconds before automatically redirecting to the home page. How do I do this? I can't seem to get delay to work for me.

Comment: Do you use jQuery 1.4.2? Because older versions don't support delay() yet.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can just use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) directly, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "/NewPage.aspx";
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [jQuery Timer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers). Here is the code (also found [in this article](http://chenz101tutorials.blogspot.com/2009/08/redirecting-page-using-jquery-timer.html)):

```
// This will hold our timer
var myTimer = {};
  // delay 2 seconds
  myTimer = $.timer(2000, function() {

  //redirect to home page
  window.location = "/RedirectTimer/Home.aspx";
});
```

Comment: Good answer, just consider if its worth marking down as it will wait for 3 seconds, rather than the 2 requested ;)

Comment: @Paul - Haha...umm...I was demonstrating the power of comments. See...you caught the bug right away because the code was so easy to read! ;-) :-p (I updated the answer to make it two seconds.)

Answer (score 4):

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "/NewPage.aspx"; }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Would [the `delay()` function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) not work for you? Vanilla JavaScript with `setTimeout()` would work equally well.

Hint: Suggesting actual code is kind of hard when you do not show your current code.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it did not work for me. I made a few adjustments which also did not work. Here is where I'm at:   <code>          <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

alert('works!');

// This will hold our timer
med = "http://www.zhospitalitygroup.com/mediterraneo/press/";
var myTimer = {};
  // delay 3 seconds
  myTimer = $.timer(1000, function() {
  //redirect to home page
  document.location = med;
});

});
</script><code>

Comment: @mark: I think your comment was meant for @JasCav's answer. Code formatting works through backticks in comments.